# Creating custom requestParam in springboot controller

Tags: spring-boot, http-request-parameters

i have a use case where the user can send following params with get request

> ```
> GET localhost/8080/users?filter=alex
> OR
> GET localhost/8080/users?suffixFilter=lex
> OR
> GET localhost/8080/users?prefixFilter=a
> ```

is it possible to add only one request param instead of 3 in controller

e.g.

instead of

```
@GetMapping("/users")
@ResponseBody
public String getFoos(@RequestParam String filter, @RequestParam String prefixFilter , @RequestParam String suffixFilter) {
    return "ID: " + id;
}
```

is it possible to create a dynamic one which includes those three variantes? I was thinking creating class like this

```
public class FilterCreteria {
    private String filter;
    private String suffixFilter;
    private String prefixFilter;
}
```

and then passing this to controller

```
 @GetMapping("/users")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getFoos(@RequestParam FilterCreateria filter) {
        return "ID: " + id;
    }
```

the problem is if i send filter=alex the other attributes in the class FilterCreteria is null and i want to avoid this null.

What i searching for:

is there other way of making this possible?
if my suggestion is ok, how to avoid null attributes when the user only sends one queryparam like filter=alex?

Comment: Use the object and instead of `@RequestParam` use `@ModelAttribute`... And read the documentation which explains all this in detail. Else use a `MultiValueMap<String, String>` as a `@RequestParam` to get all the parameters being send. But I suggest the object route as that makes it easier.

Comment: What do u mean by using the object

Comment: The `FilterCriteria` thing instead of a random `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: If i use the object and the user send only prefixfilter then the other attributes will be null. How to get rid od it?

Comment: You don't. Why is it a problem if those are `null`... Your downstream code should handle that.

Comment: I want to forward  the object without any null via resttemplate

Comment: So configure it that the JSON ignores `null` values.

Comment: How to do that, can u apply an example to my posted code plz

Comment: You can just annotate your object with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` which will leave out all `null` fields in the generated json.

Comment: What if i dont convert it to json. Is there other ways?